# SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=unknown state: unknown protocol rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, openssl, ssl-certificate, ubuntu-14.04

I've been having issues setting up mailer on to my ruby on rails application, I know that this question was asked before but none of the other one solved my problem so I said I'll give it a try.

My current development log is.

```
Rendered example_mailer/sample_email.html.erb within layouts/mailer (0.1ms)
  Rendered example_mailer/sample_email.text.erb within layouts/mailer (0.0ms)

ExampleMailer#sample_email: processed outbound mail in 13.5ms

Sent mail to admin@exampler.ca (20.8ms)
Date: Wed, 09 Aug 2017 13:46:42 +0000
From: noreply@exampler.ca
To: admin@exampler.ca
Message-ID: <598b1242ae925_95383fe3f1445b7852366@team-version-5166637.mail>
Subject: Hello from Postmark
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
 boundary="--==_mimepart_598b1242ad242_95383fe3f1445b78522a1";
 charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
html-body: <strong>Hello</strong> dear Postmark user.
track-opens: true


----==_mimepart_598b1242ad242_95383fe3f1445b78522a1
Content-Type: text/plain;
 charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

Hi
Sample mail sent using smtp.

----==_mimepart_598b1242ad242_95383fe3f1445b78522a1
Content-Type: text/html;
 charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

<html>
  <body>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' http-equiv='Content-Type' />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hi </h1>
    <p>
      Sample mail sent using smtp.
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
  </body>
</html>

----==_mimepart_598b1242ad242_95383fe3f1445b78522a1--

Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 102ms (ActiveRecord: 60.6ms)

OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError (SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=unknown state: unknown protocol):
  app/controllers/confessions_controller.rb:42:in `block in create'
  app/controllers/confessions_controller.rb:39:in `create'


  Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.5/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.erb (4.5ms)
  Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.5/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (3.8ms)
  Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.5/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (1.7ms)
  Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.5/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.html.erb within rescues/layout (35.9ms)
```

and my application.rb is

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :postmark
config.action_mailer.postmark_settings = { :api_token => "A_token" }
```

and my

It appears that if i try to connect using the command line with something like:

> openssl s_client -connect aristo4stu3.bgu.ac.il:443 -no_tls1 ####this works
>
> openssl s_client -connect aristo4stu3.bgu.ac.il:443   #### this doesn't work

my ruby version

```
ruby 2.3.0p0 (2015-12-25 revision 53290) [x86_64-linux]
```

my openssl version

```
OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
```

linux version:

```
Linux team-version-5166637 4.9.17-c9 #1 SMP Thu Mar 23 01:38:54 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Any help will be appreciated, Thank you!